# Ordering varchar field with decimals numbers and none decimal numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Varchar field with decimals numbers and none decimal numbers.

Ex:

```
100.02
99
9
200.56
500.4
10.1
6
```

How do i order it to display in ASC order

I tried below codes with no luck

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC LIMIT 0, 9
```

Also

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY convert(price, decimal) DESC LIMIT 0, 9
```

But none of the above codes seems to work. Can someone point me out the proper way to do this.

Comment: from what i see of the data you have posted there is no reason **not** to make the field a FLOAT unless you are expecting VARCHARs in which case you might to ask yourself why you need to store FLOAT and VARCHARs  together when you can see yourself only sorting FLOATS

Comment: change the field type

Comment: @Memor-X when using a INT field is not saving decimals that's why I'm using VARCHAR field

Comment: @max i never said INT, i said [FLOAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) *" For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999"*

Comment: as the field is called price, decimal is (most likely) better than float "The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting issue is due to the use of a sting type field for a number, it will never sort as a human would expect.

if the field type is price, you should never use float, instead you should use
DECIMAL or NUMERIC

> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data.

you don't want an "approximate" value for a price

> The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data value